# How can i retrieve the feature names from my pipeline which uses columntransformer & SelectKbest?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, pipeline

I am using coluntransfomer to and selectkbest on for my pipeline e.g.:

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('imputer',SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, fill_value=0) ),('scaler', StandardScaler())])
 preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_cols),
                                ('cat', categorical_transformer, cat_cols)])

    
sel = SelectKBest(k=60)
models_new = {  'xgb': Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),('sel',sel),('clf', XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softprob',n_jobs=-1))]),#tree_method='gpu_hist'
                       'rf': Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),('sel',sel),('clf', RandomForestClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 42,n_jobs=-1))]) }
```

I then run gridsearch on the above using hypyerclassifersearch module (which is gridsearchcv) and i will omit since too large to paste. But the output is bestmodel which is a pipeline. In this case random forest was the best. e..g best_model looks like:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor',
                 ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('num',
                                                  Pipeline(steps=[('imputer',
                                                               SimpleImputer(fill_value=0)),
                                                                  ('scaler',
                                                                   StandardScaler())]),
                                                  ['amount','sales','costs',....']),
                                                 ('cat',
                                                  OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'),
                                                  [
                                                   'country'
                                                   ])])),
                ('sel', SelectKBest(k=60)),
                ('clf',
                 RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=7,
                                        n_jobs=-1, random_state=42))])
```

I can get feature names from applying the preprocessor such as below:
get feature names is :

```
def get_feature_names(coltra):
        from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
        from numpy import arange
        """Get feature names from all transformers.
        Returns
        -------
        feature_names : list of strings
            Names of the features produced by transform.
        """
        check_is_fitted(coltra)
        feature_names = []
        for name, trans, column, _ in coltra._iter(fitted=True):
            if trans == 'drop' or (
                    hasattr(column, '__len__') and not len(column)):
                continue
            if trans == 'passthrough':
                if hasattr(coltra, '_df_columns'):
                    if ((not isinstance(column, slice))
                            and all(isinstance(col, str) for col in column)):
                        feature_names.extend(column)
                    else:
                        feature_names.extend(coltra._df_columns[column])
                else:
                    indices = arange(coltra._n_features)
                    feature_names.extend(['x%d' % i for i in indices[column]])
                continue
            if not hasattr(trans, 'get_feature_names'):
                # ADDED SECTION A
                if hasattr(coltra, '_df_columns'):
                    if ((not isinstance(column, slice))
                            and all(isinstance(col, str) for col in column)):
                        feature_names.extend(f'{name}_{col}' for col in column)
                    else:
                        feature_names.extend(
                            f'{name}_{col}'
                            for col in coltra._df_columns[column]
                            )
                else:
                    indices = arange(coltra._n_features)
                    feature_names.extend(['x%d' % i for i in indices[column]])
                continue
                # END SECTION A
            # ADDED SECTION B
            gfn_args = inspect.getfullargspec(trans.get_feature_names).args
            args_to_send = []
            if ('input_features' in gfn_args) and \
                    not isinstance(column, slice):
                args_to_send = [column]
            feature_names.extend([name + "__" + f for f in
                                    trans.get_feature_names(*args_to_send)])
            # END SECTION B
        return feature_names


features = get_feature_names(best_model['preprocessor'])
```

Applying that i get the features names i need. My question is how do i get *both* the feature names i need from columntansformer *and* the selectKbest ones?

e..g when i do the below i get the indices for the 60 columns chosen but unsure how i can use the features above after columntransformer which is a list of column names to this ?

```
    mask = pipe['sel'].get_support(indices=True)

array([ 14,  20,  39,  40,  47,  50,  58,  76,  78,  79,  90,  94,  97,
        99, 116, 117, 121, 124, 127, 128, 129, 130, 135, 141, 148, 153,
       155, 156, 159, 161, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 172, 174, 176, 177,
       182, 187, 193, 194, 195, 197, 198, 200, 201, 204, 205, 206, 207,
       208, 210, 211, 212, 215, 217, 227, 230])
```

###### note i would like the feature names after transformations have been applied so pipe.named_steps['preprocessor'].transformers_[0][2] or pipe.named_steps['preprocessor'].transformers_[1][2] doesn't give me the col names after transformation has occured.